# Format On Save is ignoring .prettierignore file

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I'm currently using Prettier for my projects on Visual Studio Code. Whenever I save, it formats. However, I recently wanted to ignore a specific file from formatting, so I did some research and found out about the `.prettierignore` file. But for some reason, it didn't work for me. I used the commands in the Terminal to debug the issue, and it seems like the **Format on Save** feature is ignoring or overriding this file.

I'm trying to ignore `src/main.tsx`, below I can see that it works from Prettiers side:

```
PS C:\Users\X> npx prettier --debug-check src/main.tsx
PS C:\Users\X> npx prettier --debug-check src/main.css
src\main.css
```

Can I somehow make it check for a `.prettierignore` file before formatting?

Comment: If the Prettier ignores file VSCode may sometimes default to another formatter. E.g. if I have ESLint not configured to warn on ignored files VSCode will think that ESLint formatter "can't format" them and will just ignore its existence, using anouther one